# jQuery UI .widgets resetting scroll positions of children when they are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, jquery-ui

I am making heavy use of jQuery UI with my latest project.  Unfortunately I've hit a major wall due to some really whacky behavior exhibited by the jQuery UI widgets when they contain elements with scrollbars for overflow.

[**Check out this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4gxEE/)

1. Scroll down in one of the `.scroll-container` elements
2. Click an accordion header
3. Click on old header - note the element was auto-scrolled to the top.

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?  It's screwing with a major plugin of mine that utilizes jQuery scrolling.  I'm flat-out lost as to what to do here!

*Perhaps this is a bug worth mentioning in the jQuery UI dev forums...*

### Edit

So far the bug has been **confirmed** in...

- Chrome - `8.0.552.231` on OSX `10.6.5`
- Safari - `5.0.3` on OSX `10.6.5` (makes sense)
- FF - `3.6.12` on OSX `10.6.5`

And is **not present** in...

- <del>FF - `3.6.12` on OSX `10.6.5`</del>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the jQuery UI dev who answered my trouble ticket:

> This is just how browsers work, as soon as you hide an element, it loses the scroll position.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. A workaround I came up with is to set the id of the ui object after creation. Then I save the scrollTop() position before I hide the object. And when I show the object again, I simply set the scrollTop() to the saved value.

```
// Set the id of the object if you have multiple objects with the same class
if ($("#divScroll").length == 0) {    // If the object does not exist with an id
    $(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").each(function () {    // Select each object via class
        strID = $(this).attr("id");
        // If the current object (selected via class) does not have an id, set id
        if (strID == undefined || strID == false) {
            $(this).attr("id", "divScroll");
        }
    });
}

// Save the scroll position before hide()
intScrollTop = $("#divScroll").scrollTop();
$("#divScroll").hide();

// Set the scroll position to the saved value after show()
$("#divScroll").show();
$("#divScroll").scrollTop(intScrollTop);
```